# Crystal Report-Convert date string (with day of week) to date format

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal report. I have a date in string format like 2015-03-25 (Wed) and I want to convert it to date format like 03/25/2015. I tried with CDate and DateValue but it returned bad date string format. Any suggestions to convert such date string to proper date format?

Comment: can you post your formula?

Comment: Hi Siva, this is the formula: DateValue(left({date_string},len({date_string})-6)), I put minus six is because to get rid of the day of week, so the final result is 2015-03-25 in date format.

Comment: Are you check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DateTime field in Crystal Reports, you will see Date and Time tab option on the Format Editor when you right click on the field and select Format Field menu item. From the Date and Time tab, you may select the desired format and select OK.

[image]

It would be recommended to use the formats you want to use.

For eg : if you are giving string format for money or decimal you may not be able to use it at its full,like you may not be able to auto sum and other properties related to the datatype you intend to use

Comment: I tried to put DateValue({date_in_string}) to a newly created template field, and it converted to date format, after that I followed your suggestion to change the format, but at the end still returns bad date format string.

Comment: whats datatype in table?

Comment: change it to datetime

Comment: I know your solution will work, but I can't change it since it's client database

Comment: Yes. Although it converted to date, and then I followed your suggestion above, but once I refresh my report, it returned bad date format string.

Comment: try out :
  totext(cdate(tonumber(left({@string},4)), tonumber(mid({@string},3,2)), tonumber(right({@string}, 2))), "ddd-dd/MMM/yyyy")

Comment: it returned "the string is non-numeric".

Comment: ToText({MyDate}, "dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: I found a solution, I trimmed the date string and then convert it to date format:  DateValue(left({date_string},len({date_string})-6)). By the way, thanks utility for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Not to do any thing in the code, Crystal Report have facility to this type of simple format.

@utility, you are near to answer.

As above image, in last `Custom Format` option, where you just go in `Date` tab and give format as

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DateFormatInCR06132007092248AM/DateFormatInCR.aspx

**Updated** : sorry for above answer, that will work if you have valid date string.
In your case, where any arbitrary string need to convert into other date format.  There is 2 option. In both case you have to extract the date and then format as you need and again combined with other sub-string.

1. Second you already done ie. crsytal report side, grab the date , format it and concatenate. this will slow down as need to process for each row.
2. SqlServer side - This option is faster from first option.

> declare @t nvarchar(16) = '2015-03-25 (Wed)'
>
> --get the acual date select SUBSTRING ( @t, 1, charindex('(' , @t ) -1 )
>   --above result give the charter datatype, so you first convert into date and then convert into other format select cast(  SUBSTRING ( @t,
>   1, charindex('(' , @t ) -1 )  as date) --convert into date select
>   convert (varchar(15) , cast(  SUBSTRING ( @t, 1, charindex('(' , @t )
>   -1 )  as date) , 103) --convert into dd/mm/yyyy format
>
> --Above is for your understand, this is the actual execution of your code (Only write the below line) select convert (varchar(15) , cast( 
>   SUBSTRING ( @t, 1, charindex('(' , @t ) -1 )  as date) , 103) + ' ' +
>   datename(dw, getdate() )

I suggest, go with Sqlserver side.

Comment: Hi Ajay2707, I've tried with your suggestion but it doesn't work, I think it is restricted by the day of week at the back of the date string. Let say my date string is 2015-03-29 (Thu), as what I've tried, I change the date string to date by using DateValue({date_string}), then I right-clicked the converted date field and customized the date format, when I refresh my report, it returned bad date format string.